# Retrieve manually edited cell value in qtablewidget

Tags: python, qtablewidget

I have a qtablewidget :

```
table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 5)
```

I update it :

```
nbrWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(item.item_nbr))
table.setItem(0,0,nbrWidget)
```

Now the user edit it to correct it.
How can I catch the value when he press returen, and launch an existing updateData()

I have read some doc but it is not clear between delegates and userrole.
I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with `signals` and how you connect Widgets to actions?

Comment: Yes already used in my little project (subclassed mouseenvent in dedicated qgraphicsscene)

Comment: There is a signal called `ReturnPressed` which you can connect to your QTableWidget. You can use it to pass the item number to your `updateData()` where the new input is being read.

Comment: I tried this self.table.returnPressed.connect(self.modifyItem) => 'QTableWidget' object has no attribute 'returnPressed', did I miss something ? It seems returnPressed exist for QlineEdit or other widget, not for QTableWidget, or I have to explicitly create/modify the signal ?

Comment: It seems that QTableWidgets do not accept the returnPressed connection (unlike QLineEdits). But in any case you can override the `keyPressEvent`. It's not the simple solution that you wished for, but it should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961355/python-qt-how-to-catch-return-in-qtablewidget

Comment: Yes does the job, just having a problem because with self.currentItem().text() I get the previous value not the new one. Need to invest it. Anyway thanks I'll post the solution when I'll solve it

Comment: Maybe call `QApplication.processEvents()` first and then ask for the currentItem().text()

Comment: Yes perfect ! thanks I guess I would have never found it myself.